# TypeScript Generic Types problem: Workaround required

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance, functional-programming, apply

#### I am stuck and I don't know what is the current **⸘workaround‽**...

> This probleme is describe in this issue: [Microsoft/TypeScript/#1213](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)...

I am trying to implement the [Chain specification](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain):

> (I need to pass a type to the `ApType` so that on line 12 (in the snippet below) the `Apply` is not *hard coded* but generic to also take types extended from any `IApply`)

```
m['fantasy-land/chain'](f)
```

A value that implements the Chain specification must also implement the Apply specification.

```
a['fantasy-land/ap'](b)
```

I did a `FunctorSimplex` which is then extended by a `FunctorComplex` then extended by the `Apply` but now that I want to extend `Apply` as a `Chain`  it is breaking...

So I need that (image below and link to code):

[image: Screenshot]

[Permalink to the code snippet *lines 11 to 22 in 7ff8b9c*](https://github.com/Luxcium/100DaysOfCode/blob/7ff8b9c695816aaf37defe24c764fe218fe19ce2/packages/apply/lib/types.ts#L11-L22)

```js
export type ApType<A = unknown> = <B = unknown>(
  ap: Apply<(val: A) => B>,
) => IApply<B>;

/* [...] */

export interface IApply<A = unknown> extends FunctorComplex<A> {
  /** `Fantasy-land/ap :: Apply f => f a ~> f (a -> b) -> f b` */
  ap: ApType<A>;
}
```

Comment: Completely unrelated to a solution, but that might just be the most blinged out combination of colors and fonts I've ever seen in a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is higher kinded type (HKT). In Typescript, HKT can be achieved using something called as `module augmentation`. Check [this](https://medium.com/@gcanti/higher-kinded-types-in-typescript-static-and-fantasy-land-d41c361d0dbe) article. You can refer [fp-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts) implementations too.